# How to Load a Sharepoint List in a Provider Hosted Web Form?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, webforms, sharepoint-2013

I have created a sample application using the [MSDN Link](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/get-started-creating-provider-hosted-sharepoint-add-ins) to get started with Provider Hosted SharePoint App. My app is getting installed into the Sharepoint website and is running fine with everything, except one.
I'm just not able to retrieve the contents of a Custom List that I created in  the same website. 
The code for it is as shown below:

```
foreach (List list in lists)
            {
                listOfLists.Add(list.Title);
                if (list.Title.Equals("XYZ_CarServiceStatus_Table"))
                {
                    CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
                    clientContext.Load(list);
                    clientContext.Load(items);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    CarListGV.DataSource = items;
                    CarListGV.DataBind();
                }
            }
```

All I get is no result:
[image]
I really need this to work. Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you loading the lists? Please post full code ... Set a breakpoint at `clientContext.Load(list)`. When this line is executed successfully, can you debug the list object? What do you see?

Comment: The code is exactly what is on the msdn page I have linked in the question. When I debug that particular line, this is what i get: The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

Answer (score 0):

Added SiteCollection to the my AppManifest.xml with Read access. Solved the issue. Silly actually.